# Following Accounts or Leads but where is the follow button

Tags: follow

In salesforce it is possible to follow accounts and leads. There is a green plus and Follow is written next to it ("Follow this account to receive updates in your feed") and this is visible in accounts and leads on the top right side under the account or lead Name.
I was working on someone elses salesforce and the green plus with follow next to it to click to follow is not visible. I tried to find it if in setup to enable it but I haven´t found it so far.
Where can I opt it in to see this for leads and accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right under the account or lead name there is the option to hide feed or show feed. In this case the feed was hidden. The follow option, to follow accounts and leads, is included in the feed and is not visible when the feed is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have **enabled** the Chatter in that organisation. And **Feed Tracking** is enabled for the Account object or Lead etc.

> **Setup** | **Customize** > **Chatter** > **FeedTracking** :

[image]